# This window keeps showing every time I login

Tags: macos, mac, finder, login

Every time I login to my Mac (Lion OS X) I keep getting this windows shown, even when I shut down without the option of reopening the windows when I log back in from here:

[image]

This is the window that keeps showing:

[image]

How on earth do I stop this for appearing all the time when I login?

Comment: Is it open when you shut down?

Comment: No, I always close everything before I shut down and I uncheck the reopen windows on login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, with the same folder. The folder is within the Steam application bundle, and for some unknown reason it gets added to your Login Items.

To stop it showing up when you login:

1. Open **System Preferences**
2. Click the **Users & Groups** icon
3. Select the **Login Items** pane
4. In the list of items, select the **MacOS folder**
5. Click the "-" button to remove it

Answer (score 1):

As the Finder window is showing the content of an application bundle, I think that application is trying to automatically execute a file at login, but it used the path to that directory, instead of the file that should be executed. The fact there is a steam.sh file could confirm my idea.
The checkbox you see on that dialog box applies only to applications you open yourself after login, and which are still open when you restart/shut down the computer. As far as I experienced, the Finder windows that were open before to restart/shutdown my Mac are re-opened when I log in, even if I don't select that checkbox.

Look for any place where an application can register a file that is automatically opened/executed at login, and remove the reference to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to `~/Library/Preferences`. `~`is an alias for your username.

2) Delete the file `com.apple.finder.plist`

3) Restart.

Answer (score 0):

You have Steam installed, which for some reason adds that folder to you Login Items list.  Go to System Preferences:Users & Groups:Login Items  and remove the Steam item from the list.